# Pandas groupby-apply: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis

Tags: pandas, join

I am performing a groupby operation on a DataFrame. On each of the group I have to rename two columns and drop one, so that each group will have the following form:

```
index(timestamp) | column-x | column-y
...              |  ....    | .....
```

The index is a timestamp and it will be common to each group. 'column-x' and 'column-y' instead will be different to each group. My goal is then to join all groups on the index so that I have a unique DataFrame such as:

```
index(timestamp) | column-x1 | column-y1 | column-x2 | column-y2 | ...
...              |  .....    | ......    |  .......  | .......   | ...
```

The function I apply to each group is (can I make inplace edit to the group while iterating?):

```
def process_ssp(df_ssp):
    sensor_name = df_ssp.iloc[0]['subsystem-sensor-parameter'] # to be used as column name
    df_ssp.rename(columns = {
        'value_raw': '%s_raw' % sensor_name,
        'value_hrf': '%s_hrf' % sensor_name,
    }, inplace = True)
    df_ssp.drop('subsystem-sensor-parameter', axis='columns', inplace=True) # since this is the column I am grouping on I guess this isn't the right thing to do?
    return df_ssp
```

Then I call:

```
res = df_node.groupby('subsystem-sensor-parameter', as_index=False).apply(process_ssp)
```

Which produces the error:

```
ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis
```

EDIT:
Dataset sample https://drive.google.com/file/d/1RvPE1t3BmjeaqCNkVqGwmokCFQQp77n8/view?usp=sharing

Comment: can you provide source table with column 'subsystem-sensor-parameter'?

Comment: Yes, I updated the post above with a sample.

Comment: @shadowtalker can you explain what part of the code you're having trouble with? Does your actual problem have anything to do with this question, code, or data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first add column `subsystem-sensor-parameter` for MultiIndex, reshape by `unstack`, sorting MultiIndex in columns by second level and chane their positons. Last convert MultiIndex by flattening with `map` and `join`:

```
res = (df_node.set_index('subsystem-sensor-parameter', append=True)
                          .unstack()
                          .sort_index(axis=1, level=1)
                          .swaplevel(0,1, axis=1)) 
res.columns = res.columns.map('_'.join)
```

Comment: This function completes without error, but it does not achieve exactly what I would like to. The res variable is a DataFrame whose index is of this type: ('nc-devices-alphasense', Timestamp('2019-03-05 00:02:40')). This creates a huge number of NaN values. Instead, I would like to have only the timestamp on the index value. How can I achieve that? By printing df_ssp in process_ssp() I can see that df_ssp has the format I need. However, res doesn't join the join the groups as I would like to, because it changes the indexes adding the subsystem-sensor-parameter to the timestamp.

Comment: @user1315621 - Missing values are expected output, because in DataFrame if some group no match are filled NaNs, so only matched groups are fileld by dates, another not.

Comment: Great! The last comment is what I was looking for. If you want to write it as an answer, and not as a comment, I will approve it as correct answer. I will work on understanding how it works ;) Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'm able to successfully apply your code and produce the output you want by iterating over the groups rather than using `apply`:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('/Users/jeffmayse/Downloads/sample.csv')
df.set_index('timestamp', inplace=True)

def process_ssp(df_ssp):
    sensor_name = df_ssp.iloc[0]['subsystem-sensor-parameter'] # to be used as column name
    df_ssp.rename(columns = {
        'value_raw': '%s_raw' % sensor_name,
        'value_hrf': '%s_hrf' % sensor_name,
    }, inplace = True)
    df_ssp.drop('subsystem-sensor-parameter', axis='columns', inplace=True) # since this is the column I am grouping on I guess this isn't the right thing to do?
    return df_ssp

groups = df.groupby('subsystem-sensor-parameter')
out = []
for name, group in groups:
    try:
        out.append(process_ssp(group))
    except:
        print(name)
pd.concat(out).shape

Out[7]: (16131, 114)
```

And in fact, the issue is in the `apply` method, as your function is not needed to produce the error:

`df.groupby('subsystem-sensor-parameter', as_index=False).apply(lambda x: x)`

evaluates to `ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis` as well.

However, this statement evaluates as we'd expect:

```
df.reset_index(inplace=True)
df.groupby('subsystem-sensor-parameter', as_index=False).apply(process_ssp)

Out[22]: 
      nc-devices-alphasense_hrf  ... wagman-uptime-uptime_raw
0                             0  ...                      NaN
1                           NaN  ...                      NaN
2                           NaN  ...                      NaN
3                           NaN  ...                      NaN
...
```

The issue is that you have a `DatetimeIndex` with duplicate values. `.apply` is attempting to combine the result sets back together, but is not sure how to combine an index with duplicate values. At least, I believe that's it. Reset your index and try again.

Edit: to expand, you see this error commonly when trying to reindex a DatetimeIndex i.e., you have an hourly index and want to convert it to a second resolution index, or usually fill in missing hours. you use reindex, but it will fail if your index has duplicate values. I'd guess that is what is happening here: the dataframes produced by the function being applied have duplicate index values and the error comes from trying to produce the output via calling reindex on a DatetimeIndex with duplicates. Resetting the index works because your index is now all unique, and the `timestamp` column is not important to this operation.

Comment: I unfortunately can't reproduce the error with two simple examples: `data = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1,2,3,4,5], 'b': [11,11,11,12,12]}, index=['q','r','r','r','t'])`, and the same with `data.index = pd.to_datetime(['2019-03-01', '2019-03-04', '2019-03-04', '2019-03-04', '2019-05-12']) `. Trying all combinations of `.groupby(level=0)`/`.groupby('b')` and various functions in the `.apply()`, like dropping columns, which result in a variety of duplicate index situations and don't seem to cause a problem.

Comment: I'm tempted to call this a Pandas bug and file a report. It's certainly not a helpful error.

Comment: @shadowtalker this isnt a bug i think. can you let us know which part of your code are you facing issue?

Comment: @anky_91 forget my code. the point of my comment is that i can't reproduce the problem described in this answer using the reasoning they described, so there's clearly something else in that data (or in that specific function) that's triggering the error

Comment: I don't think the indexes in your example and your real data are the same. If you follow the stacktrace down, your data requires the use of the `pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_indexer_non_unique` method whereas your example code does not. Suffice to say that your real data has a complicated index that is causing some issue. I'm still trying to debug my way to the cause, though...to be clear, the issue seems to be using `timestamp` alone, as it causes the same error even as `str` type.

Comment: Since the bounty is about to expire, I'll award it to this answer pre-emptively. If I find some time this week I'll work on reproducing the problem as well.